# VNC connections from a mac is very slow

Tags: vnc

I am new to Ubuntu and I am looking for ways to speed up VNC connections from a Mac. I am on a 1 gigabit LAN and I am using the macOS built in VNC client.

Comment: which ubuntu version ?

Comment: which version of mac ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the resolution setting on ubuntu side , that can be better .

On the Mac , i use TurboVnc ( https://sourceforge.net/projects/turbovnc/ ) and TurboVnc has many settings to tune the bandwidth ( Menu preferences/encoding )

My best setting With TurboVnc  was this :

1. Allow JPEG COMPRESSION
2. JPEG chrominance 4X
3. JPEG image quality 50
4. Compression level 6

Comment: I'm using from Windows to Mac and works very well with configs above